# AndEngine LiveWallpaper UpdateHandler stops

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper, game-physics

i am working with the AndEngine live wallpapers. i have made a live wallpaper in which i have registered a updatehandler with the sprite it works perfectly.After setting this wallpaper the updatehandler still works fine but when i switch off the screen and again switch on the screen the updatehandler stops working and wallpapers becomes still image,dont know whats the problem and where is the problem,please help,Thank you.

Comment: It seems that the update handler gets cleaned up when you switch the screen off. Can you re-register the UpdateHadler in your onResume() method?

Comment: thank you JohnEye for your expert opinion i will definitely try it but this time i tried to call onResume() in onPause() and getting required result till now, but if this also gets fail i will try your expert opinion thank you :)

Comment: I'm no expert, but thanks :-)